# Merge two working svn copies

Tags: svn

I got two working copies of SVN

Ex:

```
CopyA is my development work 

CopyB is a tagged branch from SVN Head
```

Now, I need to merge copyA with copyB locally, test and commit back to tagged branch.

Is there a good way to merge copyA with copyB locally ?

Comment: Learn **correct** (sic!) terminology, re-write question, [RTFM docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re16.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything in your dev work is commited to CopyA, it's a matter of going to your working copy of CopyB and merging it with the server side CopyA:

```
svn merge -r 250:HEAD http://svn.yourserver/repos/branches/CopyA
```

where 250 is the revision you created CopyB at.

(I'm assuming CopyB was branched out from CopyA)